# How do I specify an NSPredicate to match strings that don't start with a letter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, core-data

This predicate is used to look up CoreData objects based on their title field. I want to fetch any objects that don't start with a letter character (a-z, A-Z).

I have tried this and variations, but I can't get it to work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ MATCHES '^[^a-zA-Z]+.*'", @"title"]
```

Comment: Try `^(?!\\p{L}).*'` or `^(?!\\\\p{L}).*'`

Comment: Instead of MATCHES, try using BEGINSWITH.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, but those don't seem to work for me. The former crashes and the latter doesn't match.

Comment: Well, if `'(?![a-zA-Z]).*'` or `'^(?![a-zA-Z]).*'` do not match, the problem is not with the regex.

Comment: Try creating your regexString first and then use it in `predicateWithFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `%K` to use a key path, rather than `%@` which uses the value:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K MATCHES '^[^a-zA-Z].*'", @"title"]
```

(I also dropped the `+` modifier as that is unnecessary in your pattern.)

HTH